# How can I convert a list of integers to a string?

Tags: list, time-date, parse-time, format

Let's say I have a list of integers, representing year, month, day for a date:

```
(2017 8 21)
```

and I want to format the list in one function call, as in

```
(format "%04d-%02d-%02d" 2017 8 21)
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I know I could assign the list to a variable and use `elt` to extract each element, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

(I really want to get YYYY-MM-DD for the first day of a given iso week, and has gotten so far as to that `(math-date-to-dt (math-parse-iso-date (format "%04dW%02d1" year week)))` will give me above mentioned list.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function to pass a function arguments
contained in a list as separate arguments. For example:

```
(apply #'format "%04d-%02d-%02d" '(2017 8 21))
```

That way you can store the list in a variable or compute it with a
function call, etc.

```
(let ((best-day-ever '(2017 8 21)))
  (apply #'format "%04d-%02d-%02d" best-day-ever))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun and profit:

```
(destructuring-bind (year month day) '(2017 8 21)
  (format "%04d-%02d-%02d" year month day))
```

An unfortunate use of eval:

```
(eval `(format "%04d-%02d-%02d" ,@ '(2017 8 21)))
```

A macro form of that:

```
(defmacro dformat (date)
  `(format "%04d-%02d-%02d" ,@date))

(dformat (2017 8 21))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a way to apply a list of arguments to a function, which I believe is what you need:

```
(let ((x '(2017 8 21))
      (f (lambda(x y z) (format "%04d-%02d-%02d" x y z ))))
  (apply f x))
```

`apply` applies a list of arguments to a given function.

Comment: Note that `apply` takes an arbitrary number of arguments, and only the last is a *list* of arguments, so there's no need for an anonymous function (see Omar's answer).